# Does Nimbus support Amazon-RDS?

Tags: amazon-rds, nimbus, cumulus

I am considering using Nimbus for a cloud application. I know that Nimbus uses [Cumulus](http://www.nimbusproject.org/docs/2.6/faq.html#cumulus) but I don't know if it supports [Amazon-RDS](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/) service (and it must because it is a requirement).

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sent an e-mail to Nimbus support and the reply to the question was the following:

> Hi Pedro,
>
> Sorry but Nimbus does not support Amazon-RDS.

I want to point out, that Nimbus support was very friendly. 
I wish the Nimbus project the best of lucks and I hope this answer saves some headaches to a lot of you.